# AngularJs - can't see a leaflet map in a ui-router view

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, leaflet, angular-leaflet-directive

I gave been using leaflet for a while now, with AngualrJs, to show maps.

Now, I want to add some complexity and use ui-router to display the map only in one state, which means in one view, which has an associated controller. However, the map does not display, and there are no error messages in the developer console.

I have created the simplest possible Plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/vXzfDKZn7FMW4aBh). It has two states, Alpha & Beta, each with a link to toggle to the other state. In the view of state Beta, there is also the [simplest possible leaflet map](https://angular-ui.github.io/ui-leaflet/#!/examples/simple-map), but, as I said, it does not display, and does not show any errors. I added a red border around it in CSS.

What am I doing wrongly?

---

The complete code follows, but you might find it easier to play with the Plunker.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
    <link rel="styleSheet" href="styles.css" />

    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"
        href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script type="application/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="application/javascript" src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="application/javascript"
        src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.11/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="application/javascript"
        src="//rawgit.com/angular-ui/ui-router/0.2.13/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.6.4/leaflet.js"></script>


    <script type="application/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
    <script type="application/javascript" src="controllers.js"></script>
</head>    
    <body ui-view></body>    
</html>
```

app.js

```
angular.module('app', [
    'ui.router'
]);

angular.module('app').config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',
    function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/alpha');

        $stateProvider.state('alpha', {
            url: '/alpha',
            templateUrl: './alpha.html',
            controller: 'alphaController'
        });

        $stateProvider.state('beta', {
            url: '/beta',
            templateUrl: './beta.html',
            controller: 'betaController'
        });
    }  
]);
```

controllers.js

```
angular.module('app').controller('alphaController', ['$state',
    function ($state) {

    }
]);

angular.module('app').controller('betaController', ['$state',
    function ($state) {
    }
]);
```

alpha.html

```
<h1>Alpha</h1>

<a ui-sref="beta" ui-sref-active="beta">Beta</a>
```

beta.html

```
<h1>Beta</h1>
<a ui-sref="alpha" ui-sref-active="alpha">Alpha</a>

<hr>

<!-- see https://angular-ui.github.io/ui-leaflet/#!/examples/simple-map -->
<leaflet id="map-simple-map" class="map_div red_border"></leaflet>
```

styles.css

```
html, body
{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.map_div
{
  height: 90%;
  width: 90%;
}

.red_border
{
    border-width: 1%;
    border-style: double;
    border-color: red;    
    padding: 0.5%;
    margin: 0.5%;    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include `leaflet.css`, `angular-simple-logger.js` & `ui-leaflet.js` on index.html:

```
<link
        type="text/css"
        rel="stylesheet"
        href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    />
    <script
        type="application/javascript"
        src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"
    ></script>
    <script
        type="application/javascript"
        src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"
    ></script>
    <link
        data-require="leaflet@0.7.3"
        data-semver="0.7.3"
        rel="stylesheet"
        href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/0.7.3/leaflet.css"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />

    <script
        data-require="leaflet@0.7.x"
        data-semver="0.7.3"
        src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/0.7.3/leaflet.js"
    ></script>
    <script
        type="application/javascript"
        src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.11/angular.min.js"
    ></script>
    <script
        type="application/javascript"
        src="//rawgit.com/angular-ui/ui-router/0.2.13/release/angular-ui-router.js"
    ></script>
    <script src="https://rawgit.com/nmccready/angular-simple-logger/master/dist/angular-simple-logger.light.js"></script>
    <script src="https://rawgit.com/angular-ui/ui-leaflet/67e9dc28d9880a9091cbf7d42de259440e77ada9/dist/ui-leaflet.js"></script>
```

and  ui-router on `app.js`:

```
var app = angular.module('app', [
    'ui-leaflet', 'ui.router'
]);
```

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/ayyyAknRtjtOO7YK)

Comment: You, sir, are a genius !!   Thanx a 1,00,000

Comment: Just curious; I started adding your changes locally and it did not work until I added `angular-simple-logger`. Why was that? Is it a requirement of one of the leaflet libraries? Btw, I will award a bountty as soon as the sytem lets me. This has been blockin gme for quite a while.

Comment: It is a requirement to install `angular-leaflet-directive`. Check [here](https://angular-ui.github.io/ui-leaflet/#!/getting-started) under `Getting started
`. If you check on the library's [official github page](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-leaflet) it is mentioned that "Include `angular-simple-logger `before `Angular-Leaflet js `files. Logger gets installed as a requirement of Angular-Leaflet with bower install or npm install. Note that if you're using the browser to load it without CommonJS (browserify, webpack) please use angular-simple-logger.js (not index.js)."